# Multiple metrics over large dataset in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have a big dataset groupped by certain field that I need to run descriptive statistics on each field.
Let's say dataset is 200m+ records and there's about 15 stat functions that I need to run - sum/avg/min/max/stddev etc. Problem that it's very hard to scale that task since there's not clear way to partition dataset.

Example dataset:

```
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+
| Department | PartName | Price | UnitsSold | PartNumber |
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+
| Texas      | Gadget1  |     5 |       100 |       5943 |
| Florida    | Gadget3  |   484 |      2400 |       4233 |
| Alaska     | Gadget34 |    44 |       200 |       4235 |
+------------+----------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

Right now I am doing it this way (example):

```
columns_to_profile = ['Price', 'UnitSold', 'PartNumber']

    functions = [
        Function(F.mean, 'mean'),
        Function(F.min, 'min_value'),
        Function(F.max, 'max_value'),
        Function(F.variance, 'variance'),
        Function(F.kurtosis, 'kurtosis'),
        Function(F.stddev, 'std'),
        Function(F.skewness, 'skewness'),
        Function(count_zeros, 'n_zeros'),
        Function(F.sum, 'sum'),
        Function(num_hist, "hist_data"),
    ]

functions_to_apply = [f.function(c).alias(f'{c}${f.alias}')
                        for c in columns_to_profile for f in get_functions(column_types, c)]

df.groupby('Department').agg(*functions_to_apply).toPandas()
```

Problem here is that list of functions is bigger than this (there's about 16-20) which applies to each column but cluster spend most of the time in shuffling and CPU load is about 5-10%.

How should I partition this data or maybe my approach is incorrect?

If departments are skewed (i.e. Texas have 90% of volume) what should be my approach?

this is my spark dag for this job:

[image]